# Determine the parameters a and b so that the function is continuous

Tags: functions, solution-verification, continuity

I did this task with the function and I got the result that a = -1 and b = 3, can someone help me and check if it is a good result or if I got the right solution.

Determine the parameters a and b so that the function is continuous:
[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser ok , thank you

Comment: *How* did you find the values $a=-1$ and $b=3$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I calculated with the help of limes, and then just included with the help of a linear system and I got a = -1 b = 3, now I don't know if it's true if I made a mistake somewhere

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Did you check the results too? I think my solution is okay?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's fine.